# Method to compute NIntegral of Trigonometric functions

Tags: numerical-integration

I don't know which method to adopt for computation of the following integrand on the unit sphere in $R^6$:

1. $
   2 r^9 \sin ^5(\text{$\theta $1}) \sin ^3(\text{$\theta $2}) \sin2(\text{$\theta $3}) \sin (\text{$\theta $4}) \left(\sin (\text{$\theta $1})\sin^2(\text{$\theta $2}) \sin ^2(\text{$\theta $3}) \sin (\text{$\theta $4}) \cos (\text{$\theta $4}) \cos (\text{$\theta $5})+\cos (\text{$\theta $1}) \cos (\text{$\theta $2})\right) \left(\cos ^2(\text{$\theta $1})-\sin ^2(\text{$\theta $1}) \left(\sin ^2(\text{$\theta $2}) \sin ^2(\text{$\theta $3}) \left(\sin ^2(\text{$\theta $4}) \cos ^2(\text{$\theta $5})-\cos ^2(\text{$\theta $4})\right)+\cos ^2(\text{$\theta $2})\right)\right)
   $
2. $2 r^9 \sin ^5(\text{$\theta $1}) \sin ^4(\text{$\theta $2}) \sin ^2(\text{$\theta $3}) \sin (\text{$\theta $4}) \left(\cos ^2(\text{$\theta $1})-\sin ^2(\text{$\theta $1}) \left(\sin ^2(\text{$\theta $2}) \sin ^2(\text{$\theta $3}) \left(\sin ^2(\text{$\theta $4}) \cos ^2(\text{$\theta $5})-\cos ^2(\text{$\theta $4})\right)+\cos ^2(\text{$\theta $2})\right)\right) \left(\sin (\text{$\theta $1}) \sin (\text{$\theta $2}) \sin ^2(\text{$\theta $3}) \sin (\text{$\theta $4}) \cos (\text{$\theta $4}) \sin (\text{$\theta $5})+\cos (\text{$\theta $1}) \cos (\text{$\theta $3})\right)$
3. $r^9 \sin ^4(\text{$\theta $1}) \sin ^3(\text{$\theta $2}) \sin ^2(\text{$\theta $3}) \sin (\text{$\theta $4}) \left(\cos ^2(\text{$\theta $1})-\sin ^2(\text{$\theta $1}) \left(\sin ^2(\text{$\theta $2}) \sin ^2(\text{$\theta $3}) \left(\sin ^2(\text{$\theta $4}) \cos ^2(\text{$\theta $5})-\cos ^2(\text{$\theta $4})\right)+\cos ^2(\text{$\theta $2})\right)\right)^2$

for $\{r,0,1\},\{\text{$\theta $1},0,\pi \},\{\text{$\theta $2},0,\pi \},\{\text{$\theta $3},0,\pi \},\{\text{$\theta $4},0,\pi \},\{\text{$\theta $5},0,2 \pi \}$,  in fact, I try to use (after some comparsion of different method) `Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"` It gives me the warning:

> The integral failed to converge after 1000100 integrand evaluations.

My question:

How to find the correct method for integrating the kind of integrand as given in the above examples?

Comment: Please post expressions in proper Mathematica syntax.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.

Comment: @Louis Yes, probably you're right, but it is hard to see the exact form of my expression in mma input form, and by the way, you can transform the tex expression easily by `ToExpression["", TeXForm]` and paste the tex expression in the position `"|"`

Answer (score 1):

I found that it can be calculated exactly and reduce the consuming  time  by use `//ExpandAll` to the integrand.